# WHERE field LIKE CONCAT( 25, '_', 153, '_', '%' )

Tags: mysql

I would like to get rows where a field begins for example by '25_15_' (25_15_Value could be accepted)

So I use this condition :

```
WHERE `id` LIKE CONCAT( 25,  '_', 15,  '_',  '%' )
```

But mySQL returns **25_153_Value** :(

Ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` is a [wild card in most SQL flavours](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/wildcards-like-operator/wildcards-underscore.php) (including MySQL), matching one character (when `%` matches 0 or more).

Also, no need to use `CONCAT` as long as you only use directly hardcoded values.

Try escaping underscores when you want to use them as regular characters:

```
WHERE `id` LIKE '25\_15\_%'
```